# relationship between arithmetic mean and standard deviation in a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, mean, standard-deviation, arithmetic

I know that *Sa* divided by *Sq* (arithmetic mean/standard deviation) on a standard normal distribution is equal to 2/(2pi)^0.5 or 0.7978 but need to have the mathematical solution. Can anyone help me with the proof?

Thank  you.

Comment: What do you mean by "the value of arithmetic mean over standard deviation"?

Comment: @Zhanxiong presumably $\dfrac{\mathbb E[|X-\mu|]}{\sqrt{\mathbb E[(X-\mu)^2]}}=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}$ for a normal distribution.  Related to the mean of a half-normal distribution

Comment: @Henry yes, that is it, but would you be able to help me with the proof?

Comment: With a standard normal this amounts to showing $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x| \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\, dx $ $=  \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^\infty x e^{-x^2/2}\, dx $ $=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}$.  The calculus is not difficult

Comment: @Henry Thank you. Can you provide more details, the expected value divided by the standard deviation of a standard normal, I'd appreciate if you could send a link to a perhaps step by step proof.

Comment: @Farzad What are the values of the mean and the standard deviation of a standard normal?

Comment: @Henry 0, and 1, yes, I get it. I don't know how to explain what I'm looking for. But thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145634/discussion-between-farzad-and-henry).

Comment: @Farzad I do not do chat but I think you have enough

Comment: What have you tried? Yes, it is related to half normal distribution, can you write down the mean of a half normal distribution?

Comment: @Zhanxiong ~ std * 0.7978

Comment: @Farzad Your answer is circular (that is the goal).  My point is:  given $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, can you write down the expression of $E[|X - \mu|]$ by using the property of half-normal distribution?